# data recovery from complete file tree of empty folders

Tags: data-recovery

I just did something dumb. I was working on a lot of different things and got side tracked by the new Jammy Jellyfish release. I decided to install it while working. Yea I know that's dumb. I got a white screen that said Oops something went wrong. I restarted the machine and it didn't boot. I started windows. The Linux partition still has every folder and the entire file tree. However a lot of the folders are empty as seen in windows and in a new Linux disk I made. I have not tried to run any type of repair on that partition for fear of loosing the data. The data should still be there but why are the folders empty and the space still used and so on? How do I recover the folders and the files inside?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, you can order by your name, everything follows as you say.

Answer (score 1):

Windows cannot natively read or write to file systems used by Ubuntu.

I suggest that you boot the installation media again, and this time choose "Try Ubuntu".

This will load a live session of Ubuntu that is loaded into your system RAM and not installed to your hard drive.  From there you can use a file manager to copy or relocate files, if they still exist.

If they no longer exist, you will need to restore your lost files from backups.